# Как передать в функцию несколько переменных через пробел?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def isEven(Ax , Ay , Bx , By , Cx , Cy):
  S = 0
  S = (Bx - Ax) * (Ay + By) + (Cx - Bx) * (Cy + By) + (Ax - Cx) * (Ay + Cy) / 2

print(isEven(input()))
```

Comment: 1.000 1.000 1.000 3.000 4.000 1.000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/untitled3/g.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(isEven(input()))
TypeError: isEven() missing 5 required positional arguments: 'Ay', 'Bx', 'By', 'Cx', and 'Cy'

Comment: Также я пробовал print(isEven(input().split()))

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте это:

```py
args = map(int, input().split())
isEven(*args)
```

Comment: Нет не помогло def isEven(Ax , Ay , Bx , By , Cx , Cy , Dx , Dy , Ex , Ey , Fx , Fy):

    S = (Bx - Ax) * (Ay + By) + (Cx - Bx) * (Cy + By) + (Ax - Cx) * (Ay + Cy) / 2
    S1 = (Ex - Dx) * (Dy + Ey) + (Fx - Ex) * (Fy + Ey) + (Dx - Fx) * (Dy + Fy) / 2
    if S > S1:
        return "1"
    else:
        return "2"
args = map(float, input().split())
isEven(*args)

Comment: @ИванМиронов Вы сделали то же самое, что и я. Только указали тип float. Увы, я не мог знать ничего о входных данных, вы не указали это в вопросе. Рад, что хоть так Вы нашли решение.

Answer (score -1):

```
def isEven(Ax , Ay , Bx , By , Cx , Cy , Dx , Dy , Ex , Ey , Fx , Fy):

S = (Bx - Ax) * (Ay + By) + (Cx - Bx) * (Cy + By) + (Ax - Cx) * (Ay + Cy) / 2
S1 = (Ex - Dx) * (Dy + Ey) + (Fx - Ex) * (Fy + Ey) + (Dx - Fx) * (Dy + Fy) / 2
if S > S1:
    return "1"
else:
    return "2"
```

args = map(float, input().split())
isEven(*args)