# Как передать в функцию несколько переменных через пробел?Python

Tags: python-3.x, функции

```
def isEven(Ax , Ay , Bx , By , Cx , Cy , Dx , Dy , Ex , Ey , Fx , Fy):

S = (Bx - Ax) * (Ay + By) + (Cx - Bx) * (Cy + By) + (Ax - Cx) * (Ay + Cy) / 2
S1 = (Ex - Dx) * (Dy + Ey) + (Fx - Ex) * (Fy + Ey) + (Dx - Fx) * (Dy + Fy) / 2
if S > S1:
    return "1"
else:
    return "2"

args = map(float, input().split())
isEven(args)
```

---

Вот такая ошибка выходит

```
1.000 1.000 1.000 3.000 4.000 1.000 1.000 1.000 1.000 6.000 7.000 1.000
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/untitled3/g.py", line 10, in 
    isEven(args)
TypeError: isEven() missing 11 required positional arguments: 'Ay', 'Bx', 'By', 'Cx', 'Cy', 'Dx', 'Dy', 'Ex', 'Ey', 'Fx', and 'Fy'

Comment: Вы уже задавали этот вопрос, и я, кстати, дал Вам верный [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/992891/339283)...

Answer (score 0):

Забыл звёздочку, перед аргументом в вызове:

```
isEven(*args)
```